# the meaning of "つくってゆしゅつしてます”?

Tags: meaning

What's the meaning of "つくってゆしゅつしてます" here?

> A：はじめに、ぱくさんのかいしゃのこと、おしえてもらえませんか。
>
> B：いいですよ、うちのかいしゃは、いろいろなきかいをつくってゆしゅつしてます。せかいじゅうにししゃがあるんですよ。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is indeed harder without kanji ;)

作って{つくって}輸出{ゆしゅつ}してます means "producing and exporting"

- 作る to produce
- 輸出 to export
- してます is spoken form of して**い**ます